# How to send the gradle task instruction from web app or any java API

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I would like to create a web UI from where we can deploy any gradle builds/tasks.
So I would like to send the parameters and start the gradle task using either JAVA API or nodejs?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll want to use the [Tooling API](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/embedding.html). This is is how IDE's such as Intellij and Eclipse invoke Gradle